# Node.js How to Rewrite URL in server.js

Tags: node.js, express, easyrtc

I am using node.js with easyrtc and need to rewrite url or remove any url after slash

please find my server.js

```
var http    = require("http");         
var express = require("express");      
var io      = require("socket.io");    
var easyrtc = require("easyrtc");      
var httpApp = express();
httpApp.configure(function() {
httpApp.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static/"));
});
var webServer = http.createServer(httpApp).listen(9099);
var socketServer = io.listen(webServer, {"log level":5});
var rtc = easyrtc.listen(httpApp, socketServer);
```

where can I add the script to rewrite url ?

Answer (score 1):

```
httpApp.configure(function() {
  httpApp.use(function(req, res, next){
    if(req.url === '/myOldRoute'){
      req.url = '/myNewRoute'
    }
    next();
  });
  httpApp.use(express.static(__dirname + "/static/"));
});
```

You can still access original URL http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.originalUrl

Comment: You forgot to call `next` in your middleware.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I didn't forget it; I assumed connect checks arity down to 2, which it doesn't https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/proto.js#L192